# Convert Curl command to C# HttpClient Code

Tags: c#, .net, curl, dotnet-httpclient

I have following curl command which i need to convert to C#

curl -X PUT --data-binary @Invoice_AGL_20210408.003.xml --user [xxxx]:[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] https://sftp.voxelgroup.net:19922/outbox/Invoice_AGL_20210408.003.xml

I implemented following code which gives an error.What can be error in the code.?

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"),     https://sftp.voxelgroup.net:19922/outbox/Invoice_AGL_20210408.003.xml"))
    {
        var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[xxxx]:[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]"));
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}"); 

        request.Content = new StringContent(new StringContent(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\inetpub\AstroWeb\BavelExport\2022_10_29_03_16\Invoice20220016014.xml")););
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-                           urlencoded"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

[image]

Tried to convert Curl command to C# code. It was not succesfully establish connection

Comment: Obligatory [You're using httpclient wrong](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: I don't see your invocation of this, but read that link - I see your error is from Result, which means you're probably trying to access the client after it was disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://sftp.voxelgroup.net:19922/outbox/Invoice_AGL_20210408.003.xml))\n    ");

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[xxxx]:[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]")));

request.Content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText("Invoice_AGL_20210408.003.xml").Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty));
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: At the end of the `request` declaration this `))\n    ` part seems to be quite unnecessary.

Comment: @PeterCsala All I did was take the OP's curl and used `https://curlconverter.com` to convert it.